# How to tell c++ linker that some classes will be added later by dlopen

Tags: g++, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have legacy c++ code that I'm trying to re-engineer.

I want to take some part of code out of the project as a ".so" shared library and load them dynamically by "dlopen".

I have written a dynamic loading mechanism which can load new modules dynamically at runtime.

Now I want to decouple existing modules from main project.

For instance I have extracted module "X" from the main project and created shared library which can be loaded later, but some part of the main project are using module X's classes directly and I can't change them yet.

I can compile the project by using module X's header files, but linker throw out "undefined reference" error.

**How can I tell c++ linker that these classes will be added later by dlopen mechanism at runtime?**

note: I can link and run project by copying created ".so" file of module X in "/lib" folder and use it when linking by "-lX" flag, but if I delete this file form the /lib folder the project fails on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I know if you use X's classes directly you have to link X.so to your program. But if you link X.so you can use dlopen in runtime.

Comment: Yes, but I want to remove linking time dependency. I changed X classes to proxy classes which call decoupled module functions.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called an import library. They contain small wrappers for all necessary functions and thus satisfy all static linker dependencies. At runtime these wrappers will load dynamic library if it's not yet loaded and forward execution to real implementation inside library.

Import libraries is a standard feature of Windows DLLs but they are not available out-of-the-box on Linux (or any POSIX system). You can implement wrappers by hand or use [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) to generate them automatically.